# CommonsCLI, mutually inclusive arguments?

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-cli

Is there a way to use CommonsCLI to create a pair of groups where one can be used if and only if an item from another group is used? (i.e. Both or Neither)

for example, given the option choices...

```
-foo       Enable foo. Must enable either bar or baz, cannot (for obvious reasons) be combined with moo.
-moo       Enable moo. Must enable either bar or baz, cannot (for obvious reasons) be combined with foo.
-bar       Set foo or moo mode to foobar or moobar. Cannot be used without foo or moo modes. Cannot be combined with baz.
-baz       Set foo or moo mode to foobaz or moobaz. Cannot be used without foo or moo modes. Cannot be combined with bar.
```

This gives valid modes of....

```
-foo -bar
-foo -baz
-moo -bar
-moo -baz
<None>
```

and invalid modes of...

```
-foo -moo [-bar / -baz / None]
-bar -baz [-foo / -moo / None]
-bar
-baz
-foo
-moo
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think commons-cli can do this, you will need to do some checks yourself after parsing via cli, e.g.

```
CommandLine cmd = parser.parse( options, args);
if(cmd.hasOption("foo") && cmd.hasOption("moo")) {
    throw new IOException("invalidoptions");
}
...
```